# Kubectl on Rancher Server not working properly

Tags: gitlab, kubectl, rancher

It is probably a stupid question, but I could not find anything useful on that topic.

I am following this tutorial to set up an automatic CI/CD pipeline:
https://rancher.com/blog/2018/2018-08-07-cicd-pipeline-k8s-autodevops-rancher-and-gitlab/

I get stuck on the Token part. I get this error:

```
unable to recognize "http://x.co/rm082018": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

It seems kubectl is not properly configured. If I call `kubectl version` I get the following output:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.2", GitCommit:"66049e3b21efe110454d67df4fa62b08ea79a19b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-05-16T16:23:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

It seems I would have to copy the `admin.conf` file into the home directory. However, this file does not exist since `kubeadm` is not installed on the rancher server. Later I tried installing kubeadm myself, calling `kubeadm init` and copying the resulting admin.conf file.

The error is still there.

So my question is:

how can I fix this?
do I have to fix this or can I get the token any other way?
Is the kubectl error normal behaviour since Rancher should handle all of this on its own?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: It looks like you cannot communicate with your cluster you are about to deploy the manifest to.

Have you either copied the kubeconfig file to ~/.kube/config or exported an env variable KUBECONFIG with the location as its value or used the cli argument --kubeconfig ?

Greetings

Comment: Thank you :D, I copied the admin.conf to the wrong directory. Please write your comment as an answer if possible so I can accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kubectl command output indicates that no kubeconfig was found on your host. You have to do one of the following:

- place a kubeconfig named config under ~/.kube/
- export an environment variable named KUBECONFIG with the kubeconfig location as its value
- use the kubectl command with the --kubeconfig ... argument

Happy hacking
Regards